# The used symbols for equality and equivalence

Tags: tag-removed, computer-science

Background: I am currently developing a general purpose programming language which allows formal verification (i.e. correctness proofs) of programs. During the development it came out that a lot of mathematics (order theory, lattice theory, cpos, etc.) is necessary to reach a sound definition.

For objects it is necessary to distinguish between identity and equality. Two objects are identical if they are indistinguishable. For this notion I have used the symbol $\sim$ (i.e. $a\sim b$ means the object $a$ is indistinguishable from the object $b$. Furthermore I allow user specific definitions of equality using the $=$ sign. I.e. $a=b$ means that $a$ and $b$ are equivalent with respect to some equivalence relation.

During my study of the needed mathematical theories I get more and more convinced that it would be better to take $=$ for identity or indistinguishability and $\sim$ for equalitiy or equivalence.

Is there a commonly accepted usage of symbols in mathematics expressing the notion of identy and equality?

P.S. For those who are interested in the definition of the programming language [here is a link to my blog](http://softwareverificaton.wordpress.com)

Comment: Depends who you are I guess, $=$ is usually equals to. For identity/definition I have seen $\equiv$, $\stackrel{!}{=}$, $\stackrel{\bigtriangleup}{=}$ or if dealing with a specific equivalence relation $\sim$.

Comment: I see $=$ is used in mathematics for equality in the sense of identity. $a=b$ usually means I can substitute $a$ by $b$ and vice versa in any formula. I think this is called Leibnitz equality. 

Comment: Unfortunately for understanding your question, most mathematicians use "equal" and "identical" as synonyms. "Indistinguishable" is sometimes weaker --- meaning that certain specific tools or criteria won't distinguish the two things, which might nevertheless be distinct. (E.g., identical twins might be genetically indistinguishable".) I would use "x=y" to mean that "x" and "y" are two names for the same entity. So = would be the strongest (i.e., smallest) possible equivalence relation. 

Comment: @Andreas: You confirm my suspicion that in mathematics "equal" and "identical" are used as synonyms, i.e. $=$ is the strongest equivalence relation. This implies that I have to reconsider my decision to use = for equality in the sense of equivalence with respect to some equivalence relation (which might not be the strongest possible) and ~ for identity (i.e. the strongest equivalence relation.

Comment: Well, if you're going to type all this on a keyboard, consider using =, or ==, or even ===, for different types of assignment, equality, and comparison (see Mathematica for example).

Comment: @Per: The different types of operator symbols to use are quite clear. The most naturals are =,==,=== as you proposed or ~ which is quite accessible form the keyboard as well. But my question is what symbol should represent which equivalence relation? And which choices are inline with the use in mathematics. From my perception = and ~ are used in mathematics with the meaning of identity (=) and equivalence (~). And if this is the case I tend to stick to this definition.

Comment: The conventions have changed over time and space.  Computer programming usage of = for assignment occurs frequently in mathematical literature.  Rather than trying to be consistent with current mathematical convention across the entire field, I recommend you have it conform to the majority of the expectations of your user base.  If this includes more analysts than logicians or foundationalists, I suggest =  for identity.  Otherwise use ~ for identity.  Gerhard "Aim For Smelling As Sweet" Paseman, 2012.10.17